# Is there a way to set a logging threshold for javascript

Tags: javascript, logging, browser

I am developing is java-script and i would like to inset of logging to my code, but i want to be able to turn it on and off with some global variable or something.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just override the method:

```
var debugging=true;

if (!debugging || "undefined" === typeof console.log) {
    console.log=function () {};
}
```